# React.js onChange={value => {}} multiple values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I am trying to abstract some source code, I know other languages but little about React.js.

I was hoping for a little more information as to why only my second `onchange` is being hit

I was hoping for some help on how to update "value" & "drag_value" onchange

```
onChange={value => {                        
    this.setState({value});
    console.log("value value")
    console.log(value, drag_value)

    if (updatemode === 'drag') {
        setProps({value});
    }
    if (updatemode === 'hybrid') {
        setProps({drag_value});
    }
}}
onChange = {drag_value => {
    this.setState({drag_value});
    console.log("drag value")
    console.log(value, drag_value)

    if (updatemode === 'drag') {
        setProps({value});
    }
    if (updatemode === 'hybrid') {
        setProps({drag_value});
    }
}}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that only your second onChange “is being hit”? Also what’s the greater context in which these functions are defined and used?

Answer (score 2):

You are decrlairing 2 function under the same name and basically overriding the first one.

it will be better to use names such as "handleChange" and "handleDragChange" or something like that , just so it will be different .

Answer (score 0):

you are overriding your 1st `handleChange` with your 2nd `handleChange`. So if u reverse their order then your `handleChange` with `value` will get hit as in javascript the final most declaration of any function is considered. To avoid this situation, give your functions different names and watch them work like a charm.
Hope this helps!!